# traffic between linux access point clients

Tags: linux, access-point

I configured access point with hostapd and dnsmasq with this tutorial:
[access point on linux tutorial](http://seravo.fi/2014/create-wireless-access-point-hostapd)

It works for me. NAT works but I would also like to have communication between clients. Client hosts don't see each other.

How can I enable communication between clients?

Comment: perhaps you disabled ping/icmp

Comment: I have ping between server and client but don't have between client and client

Comment: This is a sign for disabled icmp among clients. Try to find the setting in the router. Usually routers and clients should be pingable whereas the router can define whether the Clients may discover other clients.

Comment: But my question is: HOW to change this on linux?

Comment: It depends. Do You use iptables?

Comment: I have this line in rc.local:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.8.0/24 ! -d 192.168.8.0/24  -j MASQUERADE

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I had to add iptables rule:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s network_address/mask -j ACCEPT
```